# Is it NP-complete to decide if chromatic and clique numbers agree?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, reductions

It is known that finding chromatic number $\chi(G)$ and clique number $\omega(G)$  are both NP-complete problems.

Is the problem

> Given graph $G$, is $\omega(G)=\chi(G)$?

NP-complete as well?

Side question: is there a name for such graphs?

Comment: In a [perfect graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph), it holds that $\chi(G') = \omega(G')$ for every induced subgraph $G'$. The two decision problems are solvable in polynomial time for perfect graphs.

Comment: I am not seeking information about subgraphs. But what is an induced subgraph?

Comment: @AJ. That's standard terminology found in about every graph theory textbook.

Comment: I think that there is no general name for graphs that have chromatic number equal to clique number. A type of graph that has the same chromatic and clique number is the complete graph. Your problem is np-hard i think.

Comment: Your problem is definitely in NP.

Comment: @AJ. But do notice that since the property holds for every induced subgraph, it also holds for the graph $G$ itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is NP-complete. See for example [this question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_test_whether_the_clique_and_chromatic_numbers_of_a_graph_are_equal) on ResearchGate.

Your problem is in NP because to show that $\omega(G) = \chi(G)$ it is sufficient to exhibit a $k$-clique and a $k$-coloring, for some $k$.

Your problem is NP-hard by reduction from 3COL. Given a graph $G$, first check whether it contains a $K_4$, and if so output some trivial No instance (say a $5$-cycle). Otherwise, add a triangle to your graph. The original graph is 3-colorable iff the new one satisfies your condition.

Comment: I don´t see how the problem is in NP, can you explain to me please?. If i have a graph and i find a clique that has length four, for instance, i can see that the chromatic number is at least four, but i still have to make sure that there is no bigger clique. And the certificate has to show me that there is no bigger clique. That problem is not in NP, i think. What i´m missing?

Comment: If there exists a $k$ coloring, then there is no $k+1$ clique.

Comment: @Ariel Yes you are right, i get it now.

Comment: I don't know, you tell me.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It looks like it is.